# How do I use mysql-connector-python with MAMP?

Tags: python, mysql

Command line mysql works as expected:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=django3 --password=django3 \
      --database=django3 --port=8889
```

producing:

```
...
Server version: 5.5.34 Source distribution
...
```

but the script below (adapted from mysql-connector-python==1.2.3 website) produces:

```
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:8889' \
     (61 Connection refused)
```

Why this should be?

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='django3', password='django3',
                              host='localhost', port='8889',
                              database='django3')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exists")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cnx.close()
```

## Note

This script **will** work using a MySQL server on the LAN but not when trying to use the local MAMP MySQL server. Thus devel environment not that portable as long as I have this issue!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a little [hunting around](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) I realised that I needed to be explicit about the unix socket that MAMP is using.

So the line in the connection expression in the test program in the question needs to be amended as follows:

```
 ...
 host='localhost', port='8889',  \
 unix_socket='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in fact, once one clicks on "Start Servers" in MAMP, the web browser automatically opens a page with the following code import `mysql.connector

config = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': 'root',
  'unix_socket': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'database': 'inventory',
  'raise_on_warnings': True,
}

link = mysql.connector.connect(**config)`. I don't know if this is a recent addition.

Answer (score 0):

find connection.py and edit:
`'unix_socket': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',`
...
`self._unix_socket = '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'`

mine: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py